# MySQL: How to SUM() a TIMEDIFF() on a group?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

So I've got a set of results that looks something like this:

```
SELECT User_ID, StartTime, EndTime, TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime) AS TimeDiff
FROM MyTable

------------------------------------------------------------------
| User_ID |       StartTime     |         EndTime     | TimeDiff |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    | 2010-11-05 08:00:00 | 2010-11-05 09:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    | 2010-11-05 09:00:00 | 2010-11-05 10:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    | 2010-11-05 06:30:00 | 2010-11-05 07:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    | 2010-11-05 07:00:00 | 2010-11-05 09:00:00 | 02:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    | 2010-11-05 09:00:00 | 2010-11-05 10:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need to group the results by `User_ID` and `SUM()` TimeDiff. If I add a `GROUP BY` clause, it doesn't `SUM()` the TimeDiff (and I wouldn't expect it to). How can I `SUM()` the TimeDiffs for each User?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.user_id,       
         SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t.endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(t.starttime))) AS timediff
    FROM MYTABLE t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Steps:

1. Use [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to convert TIME to seconds for math operation
2. Sum the difference
3. Use [SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to convert the seconds back to TIME

Based on the sample data, I'd have just suggested:

```
  SELECT t.user_id,       
         TIMEDIFF(MIN(t.startdate), MAX(t.enddate)) AS timediff
    FROM MYTABLE t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

> NOTE: There is a bug in this code if you are using datetime.
>   TIME_TO_SEC only converts the time section so you end up with big
>   negatives if the clock goes past midnight. Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP instead
>   to do the sum. Also SEC_TO_TIME maxes out at values greater than
>   3020399 seconds e.g. SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(3020400)); If you
>   see this value 838:59:59 you've reached the max and probably just need
>   to divide by 3600 to just show hours.

Comment: Damn, should've known about `TIME_TO_SEC` earlier, me and my kludgy `CONCAT`'s with random date.... +1 for you!

Comment: @Wrikken: epoch timestamps weren't working so good, so I had to improvise :)

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific. The Start/End times are actually datetimes. Does that change your answer?

Comment: also, your second answer wouldn't be accurate since if there were gaps in times, it would include those gaps as if there wasn't.

Comment: That's what OMG was implying (that if you didn't have gaps, like in you testdata, the second would be the more optimal solution :) )

Comment: @Andrew: You're the one with the data - do you see an issue when you *test* the query?  It didn't for me, based on the sample data.

Comment: This appears to give me negative values for dates across midnight which throws the number out. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Thank you May God Bless

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your workaround for the bug. My results are getting the max value of 838:59:59 and dividing my answer by 3600 gives me the incorrect amount of hours.  Can you please provide an example of what your workaround is in the event that both start and end times max out and your answer maxes out? Thanks

Comment: Please remove your sample query "Based on the sample data, I'd have just suggested" as it's misleading that it's part of an accepted answer.  It will return inaccurate results for most real life scenarios

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, your only option is to cast to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`s and do some integer calculations, substituting a random date (I chose 2000-01-01) for TIME columns without a date.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(
    DATE_ADD('2000-01-01 00:00:00',
       INTERVAL 
       SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2000-01-01 ',TimeDiff)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00')
       SECOND),
    '2000-01-01 00:00:00')
FROM MyTable;
```

Because it may *seem* you can `SUM` TIME columns, but actually they will be cast to nasty integers or floats which will not follow time specifications (try it with a sum of minutes > 60 and you'll see what I mean).

---

For the ones who claim you can `SUM` time columns:

```
mysql> create table timetest(a TIME);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO timetest VALUES ('02:00'),('03:00');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT SUM(a) FROM timetest;
+--------+
| SUM(a) |
+--------+
|  50000 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT TIME(SUM(a)) FROM timetest;
+--------------+
| TIME(SUM(a)) |
+--------------+
| 05:00:00     |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- seems ok, but wait
mysql> INSERT INTO timetest VALUES ('02:30');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT TIME(SUM(a)) FROM timetest;
+--------------+
| TIME(SUM(a)) |
+--------------+
| 07:30:00     |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- and now, oh ye unbelievers:
mysql> INSERT INTO timetest VALUES ('01:40');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT TIME(SUM(a)) FROM timetest;
+--------------+
| TIME(SUM(a)) |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- why is that? because it uses integer arithmetic, not time - arithmetic:
mysql> SELECT SUM(a) FROM timetest;
+--------+
| SUM(a) |
+--------+
|  87000 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- that cannot be cast to time
```

Comment: Nope, it will not. I'll edit in an example which has minutes not amounting to `0` in it in a moment.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I didn't take enough time to see that 1:59 + 1:59 doesn't equal to 3:18 :-p.

Comment: Hehe, out here, it's fine, could you believe I had a payroll system running on this incorrect assumption for several weeks a long long time ago? Angry mobs all around :)

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific. The Start/End times are actually datetimes. Does that change your answer?

Comment: A little, OMG's answer would still be more appropriate in that case: `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime))))`

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you use [TO_SECONDS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) instead:

```
SELECT t.user_id,       
         SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TO_SECONDS(t.endtime) - TO_SECONDS(t.starttime))) AS timediff
    FROM MYTABLE t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this bug, a good alternative is to use TIMESTAMPDIFF and then get the sum of the column you create.

```
select(sum(df.elapse)/60 as diff
from( SELECT c1.start, c1.end, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,c1.start,c1.end) as elapse
from c1) df
```

> Note of caution: You will get very close to the actual number of hours but may be a few decimal points off. See floating point rounding for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a time tracking app. In short, I converted all intervals into seconds, added them up, and converted back to TIME format.
I am a beginner, so please excuse any clumsiness in the code. I always welcome feedback.

CREATE table time_segments (segment_id int not null auto_increment primary key, sign_in DATETIME, sign_out DATETIME, Seconds INT not null, Display TIME not null, user_id INT);

UPDATE `time_segments` SET `Seconds`=TIME_TO_SEC(-TIMEDIFF(`sign_in`,`sign_out`));

UPDATE `time_segments` SET `Display`=SEC_TO_TIME(Seconds);

INSERT INTO time_segments (sign_in, sign_out, user_id) VALUES ('2019-03-12 14:01:00', '2019-03-12 16:45:00', 1), ... ;

mysql> select * from time_segments;

| segment_id | sign_in             | sign_out            | Seconds | Display  |

|          1 | 2019-03-12 14:01:00 | 2019-03-12 16:45:00 |    9840 | 02:44:00 |

mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(Seconds)) AS 'Payperiod Hours' FROM time_segments;

| Payperiod Hours |
+-----------------+
| 49:29:00        |

Answer (score -1):

Will it work for your?

`SELECT User_ID, TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime))) AS TimeDiff

FROM MyTable GROUP BY User_ID`

Comment: AFAIK, `SUM` on `TIME` values gives nasty results (`01:30 + 02:42` becomes `0130 + 0242` => `0372` => invalid time / NULL.

Comment: Wrikken is correct - I got null as a result when testing this based on the sample data.

Comment: +1. You are right guys. Wrong guess, I tried it and it worked properly if the difference doesn't have minute/second parts. I missed the point that time may also have minutes/seconds :(