# how to get the sum of the date difference?

Tags: php, mysql

my data in table is like this

```
ds_start_time -> 09:00:00 , ds_end_time-> 09:30:00
ds_start_time -> 09:00:00 , ds_end_time-> 10:30:00
ds_start_time -> 10:00:00 , ds_end_time-> 10:30:00
ds_start_time -> 09:30:00 , ds_end_time-> 10:30:00
```

i want the difference of date and sum that difference 
for that i put this in query

```
SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(ds_end_time,ds_start_time)) 
FROM www
WHERE abc='123'........
```

but at the end i am getting 2058800.000000 . From this how can i get total hrs mins and sec.
 Or any other method .Plz suggest.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Is it MySQL?

Comment: USe TIME_TO_SEC and SEC_TO_TIME like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102480/mysql-how-to-sum-a-timediff-on-a-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do this in MySQL if you know how:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM
    (TIME_TO_SEC(ds_end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(ds_start_time))
                 ) AS timediff     
 FROM www 
 WHERE abc = '123'
```

Note that if there are many rows that have `abc = '123'` then you will probably get double counts, in that cause you migth want to try:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    (MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(ds_end_time)) - MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(ds_start_time)))
                 ) AS timediff     
 FROM www 
 WHERE abc = '123'
```

Comment: @user827726 try this as Johan said this will the best i have seen

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier to do using PHP instead of SQL.  Consider getting the actual times out and then looping through them.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($results as $val) {
    $total += strtotime($val['ds_end_time']) - strtotime($val['ds_start_time']);
}
```

Then with $total, you have the total milliseconds to do what you want with.