# time difference grouped by 2 different parameters

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if anyone could help me with a current problem i am having.

I have a database table which has the following columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh3nx.png)

I have various different Areas which can have the same product and what i am looking to do is to sum the difference for all the different products in their respective areas. for example  in the table above i would get the below results ( product 1 in area 1 total is 3 minutes etc)

```
Area    Product     Time

Retail  Product 1   00:03:00'

Packing Product 2   00:02:00'
```

The start and stop columns have the DATETIME datatype

I have tried sum(timediff(stop,start)) and group it by product but this does not appear to work.

Consequently I also want to sum the difference based on the area bit no matter what I put in i always get 181

I would appreciate any help on this

Comment: I'm a little confused with your sample data: You don't really have 2 columns called `start`, do you? Also, for the first 2 rows, the 1st column happens before the 2nd column; for the last 2 rows, the 1st column happens **after** the 2nd column.

Comment: Dont know how i did that? but you are right one column is start and the other is stop  and the stop column will always happen before the start column

Comment: Do you mean that the `start` column will always happen before the `stop` column?

Comment: i'm having a nightmare but yes you are right.

Comment: BTW I tried following this thread but to no avail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102480/mysql-how-to-sum-a-timediff-on-a-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is group by your area and product, and sum the times for each. The answer here should [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102480/mysql-how-to-sum-a-timediff-on-a-group). For your query, you'll just need something like this:

```
select
    area
    ,product
    ,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`stop`) - TIME_TO_SEC(`start`))) as timediff
from products_in_area
group by area, product
```

If you're not tied to showing the end result as a `TIME` value (e.g. you can do the formatting in your calling application), your query would look a bit cleaner:

```
select
    area
    ,product
    ,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `start`, `stop`)) Minutes
from products_in_area
group by area, product
```